# Power Query average based on multiple criteria and grouped

Tags: excel-formula, dax, powerquery

I am new to power query and the data model function in Excel and need some help please to try and translate an Excel formula into DAX formula which I can add to my table.  I have tried to search an answer for the last couple of days but can't quite find a solution and now really need some help!

The result I am looking for is the average compa-ratio for all new hires in the same job and country.

The fields I have as part of the criteria are:

Compa-Ratio (what I want to average)

I want to average by each of these fields-criteria:
"Country & Job Code" is the grouping i want used for the average result
"New Hire" = New Hire
"Compa-Ratio" does not = null and does not equal "no data"

My current excel formula is this:

'IF(AND([@[Compa Ratio]]>0,[@[New Hire]]="New Hire"),AVERAGEIFS([Compa Ratio],[Country and Job Code],[@[Country and Job Code]],[New Hire],"New Hire"),"")

I tried to create a measure in Power Query (not sure that is the right way to go or add a calculated field to my table in the PQ view?) but I couldn't figure out how to average this using the grouping for "Country & Job Code"

```
=AVERAGEX(
FILTER('mytable',
'mytable'[New Hire] = "New Hire" && NOT(ISBLANK([Compa Ratio]))
),[Compa Ratio]
)`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following as a **Measure**:

```
CR AVG:=
  var result = 
    CALCULATE(
      AVERAGE('mytable'[Compa Ratio]),
      FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT('mytable', 'mytable'[Country and Job Code]),
        'mytable'[New Hire] = "New Hire" && NOT(ISBLANK([Compa Ratio]))
      )
    )
  return 
    IF(SELECTEDVALUE('mytable'[New Hire]) <> "Existing, result)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This is almost there as the calculation works for the grouping of "Job Code & Country" and "New Hire".  However, it is adding the average calculation in the rows for Existing employees too and I just want that average to appear if the employee is a New Hire.  The condition I want to add in as well as excluding blanks, is to 'exclude anyone in the New Hire field where it = "Existing".

Comment: Try the updated answer above, it that what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you Sam.  I initially tried this formula by adding a Measure from the PP menu but I was getting an error saying 'The measure formula must start with an equals sign'  I amended to add an = sign at the front but that doesn't work.  I tried removing the text 'CR AVG:' as I have given my measure a Measure Name in the new measure editor box.  That also gives an error about invalid expression.  Tried to add directly into my table in PP as a field as per your example, but it doesn't like that either.  It seems to be that last line it doesn't like (i added the quote " to end of word "Existing")

Comment: Can you share a screen grab like mine above, would like to see if there are any syntax errors. Also which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I actually used your original formula where it also puts the calculation against the Existing employees as that helps me for another calculated field.  Thank you so much for helping with this, much appreciated